# How to control the volume format options on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: ntfs, diskmanagement, format

I'm working on developing a standard build for our environment and our security controls require all volumes to be NTFS. Is there a way to control the available choices when formatting a volume? Registry would be ideal so I could implement it in Powershell DSC. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the resource **xDisk** : used to initialize, format and mount the partition as a drive letter.

Part of **xStorage** module available [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/xStorage)